# Manufacture of High Temperature Superconductor Circuit Trace

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, superconduction

How would you go about making circuit traces out of high temperature superconductor (HTS)? Low temp superconductor traces have been made with pure tin, lead-tin, etc. But those materials are much easier to work with. My guess is pulsed laser deposition or chemical vapor deposition. How would that work? (choice of substrate, masking, etc.) Are there other ways? Are there specific HTS compounds that are better suited?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.